# Android WebView login on Android

Tags: android, asp.net, authentication, passwords

I have built app that display asp pages using WebView but some of the page want the authentication (Username ,Password )  to login I want my application to auto login to this page using Username and Password from my Application

This is my code:

---

```
public class eadvantage extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eadvantage);


     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.ucsi.edu.my/advantage/new/main.asp");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUserID", "12345));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtPassword", "12345"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.ucsi.edu.my/advantage/new/main.asp");


        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie.. here is solution.. but doesnt sound good at all

1) Create a Activity for login.. this can be initiated from menu options in your app or make this your default activity so that whenever your app is launched 1st login screen is displayed 1st

2) Get the login credentials and authenticate them.. if passed than store them in cookies.. I guess android apps can write to cookies

3) Next in your ASP.net website check if any cookies exists.. if yes.. get the username & pwd values and make them auto login (this should simple.. as we do it often when user selects remember me option in login form)

So now when ur webview is launched .. users to be logged in automatically